# Find files modified in the last 2 days for specific extensions?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I searched the find command to find files modified in the last day, however I havent been able to find a way to limit the results to only 3 extensions and it returns me a lot of files, due to my system generating cache files each day

I want to filter only
.xml
.phtml
.php

Anyone has a good approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the '-name' find option and combine several of them with 'or' ('-o'):

```
find . -mtime 0 \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.phtml" \)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint. Fixed it.